# Oracle PL/SQL Output Query from Procedure without output argument

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to output a table from a select query within a procedure.
Essentially, print query output upon procedure execution.

For example table: my_table

```
     A      B
------ ------
     1      6
     2      7
     3      8
     4      9
     5     10
```

Where I could run something like the following code with no output argument

```
SQL> create or replace procedure myproc
2       as
3    begin
4       print (select * from my_table;)
5    end;
6    /


Procedure created.


SQL> execute myproc


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

     A      B
------ ------
     1      1
     2      2
     3      3
     4      4
     5      5
```

Comment: Not possible in a procedure. You can use a `function` inplace of `Procedure` and achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 12c, You can accomplish this using `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc AS
  cur1 sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur1 FOR SELECT * FROM my_table;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur1);
END;
/ 

execute myproc;
```

Prior to 12c, you could do this with `DBMS_SQL`, however you need to know the column names and data types.

This link has the details for such implementation.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/System-Packages/Dynamicselectstatementandrowfetch.htm

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I ended up having to use an implementation similar to that in the link you provided. Unfortunately, the system we're using hasn't been updated to 12c yet.